# How to split words using sci-kit learn DictVectorizer?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have a dataset that contains dictionary-like records. Each value in the dictionary contains text:

```
[{name: 'text one', feature_two: 'text two'}, ...]
```

By using a DictVectorizer I get the tokenization made by the entire content of each value in the record, for example

```
{'name=text one': 1, 'feature_two=text two': 23, ...}
```

I would like to split the words inside the values in this way:

```
{'name=text': 1, 'name=one': 1, 'feature_two=two': 23, 'feature_two=text': 11 ...}
```

*numbers are random, do not mind them

Now I'm doing something like this:

```
file_path = 'myFile.csv'
all_data = list(csv.DictReader(open(file_path, 'rU')))

dataset = [ {'name': record['name'], 'feature': record['feature'] } for record in all_data ]
target = [record['y'] for record in all_data ]

vec = DictVectorizer()
xs = vec.fit_transform(dataset).toarray()
```

How do I need to change my pipeline in order to get what I want?